# Curl giving me an error Failed sending HTTP request what does it mean

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery to call a php file to get data from an API. It worked fine before but then I changed the way you log in and now suddenly I get an error 'Failed sending HTTP request' The API key is 100% correct and it really makes no sense that it worked before and now suddenly not. The login has nothing to do with the file that gets the data except setting the API key which I checked and is correct.

Here is the Ajax request function:

```
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "overview-left.php",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".leftContent").html(data);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $(".leftContent").html(error);
            },
        });
```

and here is the php file that gets the data.

```
<?php
session_start();

$key = $_SESSION['apikey'];
function getData($pageNum, $key)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url = "https://api.website.com/v2/sales?page_number=" . $pageNum;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,   $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Key ' . $key,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion'
    ));

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if (!$result) {
        die("Curl error: " . curl_error($curl));
    }
    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    $item = $data['sales'];
    return $item;
}

function showRecords($key)
{
    $allrecords = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
        $record = getData($i, $key);
        $allrecords[] = $record;
    }

    foreach ($allrecords as $record) {
        foreach ($record as $row) {
            $sum[$row['product_title']] ??= 0;
            $sum[$row['product_title']] += $row['selling_price'] * $row['quantity'];
        }
    }
    $rowcount = 0;
    $showResults = 10;

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead><tr><th class='image'></th><th class='wide-title'>Product Title</th><th class='number'>Revenue</th></tr></thead>";

    arsort($sum);
    foreach ($sum as $key => $value) {
        $rowcount++;
        echo "<tr>
        <td class='centerCol'><img src='placeholder.png'/></td>
        <td>" . $key . "</td><td class='centerCol'>" . "R" . $value . "</td></tr>" . PHP_EOL;
        if ($rowcount == $showResults) {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

showRecords($key);
```

Why would I suddenly now get such an error and what does it mean?

The file is not doing anything when I run it. Why is it not making the request with curl?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: _"and now suddenly I get an error 'Failed sending HTTP request'"_ - where from, exactly? Inside the browser, regarding your AJAX request? Or as a response from the attempt to make that cURL request?

Comment: I solved it thanks I found a space in the data for the key yet the space does not show when I look at the POST request, which is why it looked correct to me. I should trim the api key but did not think it necessary as nobody would edit the api keys in the database. I honestly don't know how the space got there cause I simply copied the api key without any spaces. Thanks for your comment I appreciate it